# Swift: Iterate and Compare Dictionary Item to Dictionary Items in Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I need to compare an item in one array of dictionaries to all the items in another array of dictionaries and find out if the first item was in the second array at all.

For example, array1 has a dictionary with `[{"name": "zach", "age": "twenty"}, {"name": "ben", "age": "fifteen"}, etc.]` in it. Array2 is similar with `[{"name" = "eli", "age": "fifteen"}, {"name" = "will", "age": "fifteen"}, etc.]`.

If zach isn't in array2, I want to add him to it. How can I take the items from the first array of dictionaries and compare them to all the items in the second array so that I'll know whether or not I should add it?

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't have duplicate key. In your ex you are having `name` key twice with in the same `Dictionary` and it is not possible.

Comment: Dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys, confirm if your program really using name key multiple times

Comment: @NiravD I've corrected the format of the dictionaries in my question. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: @Gibraltar You haven't respond is it working now after edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary` doesn't have duplicate key. In your ex you are having `name` key twice with in the same `Dictionary` and it is not possible, but if you have array something like below.

```
let array1 = [["name": "zach"], ["name": "eli"], ["name": "ben"]]
var array2 = [["name": "eli"], ["name" : "will"]]
```

Then you can try something like to add `zach` and `ben` name in array2.

```
let array2Name = array2.flatMap({$0["name"]}) // ["eli", "will"]       
array2 = array1.reduce(array2) { !array2Name.contains($1["name"] ?? "") ? $0 + [$1] : $0 }
print(array2)
```

**Output**

```
[["name": "eli"], ["name": "will"], ["name": "zach"], ["name": "ben"]]
```

**Edit:** You are facing this issue because you are having array with type `[[String:Any]]` and in question you are showing as array of type `[[String:String]]`, so change above code like this will works for you.

```
let array2Name = array2.flatMap({$0["name"] as? String}) // ["eli", "will"]
array2 = array1.reduce(array2) { !array2Name.contains($1["name"] as? String ?? "") ? $0 + [$1] : $0 }
print(array2)
```

Comment: I like this answer more than mine, both because it considers the 'add to array' requirement the OP added, and because map.reduce is a cool (and usually efficient) function.

Comment: @dylanthelion Thanks mate :)

Comment: @NiravD I'm seeing errors and 2 Fix-it suggestions until I get the following     `let array2Name = array2.flatMap({$0["name"]})
                array2 = array1.reduce(array2) { !array2Name.contains(where: $1["name"] as! (Any) throws -> Bool? ?? "") ? $0 + [$1] : $0 }
                print(array2)` which ultimately throws me the error of `Cannot convert value of type '(Any) throws -> Bool? to expected argument type '(Any) throws -> Bool?` which I haven't been able to get around yet.

Comment: @Gibraltar The problem is you are having array with type `[[String:Any]]`, check my edited answer to make code working.

Comment: @Gibraltar Have you try edited answer, is it working now?

Comment: @NiravD I just tested it out today and it is working great! Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @Gibraltar Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your question may be more complicated, but Dictionary is Equatable based on its contents, which means that you can iterate over the first Array, and query the second Array, as to whether it contains the same Dictionary. Like this:

```
let array1 : [Dictionary<String, String>] = [["one" : "two"], ["three" : "four"]]
let array2 : [Dictionary<String, String>] = [["one" : "two"], ["three" : "five"]]
var doesContain = false
for dict in array1 {
    if array2.contains(where: { $0 == dict} ) {
        doesContain = true
    }
}
print(doesContain) // Should be true in this case, because both arrays contain ["one" : "two"]; if they had no duplicates, doesContain would remain false
```

Comment: thanks, but the issue is that the dictionaries will likely be slightly different, so I can't do a direct comparison

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to have a new array of unique dictionaries. This is what I can suggest you:

```
let array1: [String] = [["name":"test1"], ["name":"test12"]].flatMap { $0["name"] }
let array2: [String] = [["name":"test1"], ["name":"test3"]].flatMap { $0["name"] }
let set = Set<String>(array1).union(Set<String>(array2))
let resultArrayOfDicts = set.map{ ["name": $0] }
```

Comment: I think that will work, but I'm running into the below error when I replace [["name":"test1"], etc. with my own arrays:

`cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Any?' to expected argument of type '(Dictionary <String, Any>) -> SegmentOfResult'`

I'll update if I'm able to work around it.